# Is there a male equivalent of "hag"?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

*Hag* is generally used for females, but what about males? Is there a male counterpart to this term?

My current understanding of the word is: an old woman who is disgruntled, a possible recluse, and has some form of bad hygiene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many more terms for ugly women than there are for ugly men --
 which seems quite unfair to me. But I found a few:

***Troll*** - This one is probably the closest male equivalent to *hag*. The male troll who lives under the bridge is fairly similar to the hag who lives in the woods. Unfortunately, "troll" has taken on a completely new meaning within social media, so it might cause a little confusion if you use it in its original sense. I saw "ogre" was mentioned above. Ogres are thought of as ugly, too, but there is also a strong connotation of great physical strength (thanks to "Dungeons & Dragons" and *Lord of the Rings*), so it might not be suitable.

***Nerd / geek / freak*** - These are terms to describe wimpy (and usually book-smart) and (sometimes) physically unattractive students or adults. Originally, a "geek" or a "freak" was a circus sideshow performer (for example, "the bearded lady" or "the smallest man in the world"). It was once very shameful to be considered a geek or a nerd, but today people are usually proud to be labeled as such. These terms are gender-neutral today, so they're not strictly analogous to a *hag*, per se.

Comment: Sorry, but nerd/geek/freak have zero to do with being a masculine version of hag.

Comment: It was just filler to make it seem like a good answer

Answer (score 2):

There are terms that are more often used for men, but they can be used to refer to women as well:

> (old) miser; curmudgeon; grouch; (old) codger; churl; crosspatch.

I agree that "ogre" could be a masculine word with a similar meaning to "hag", but it also has a feminine form: "ogress".

I can't think of any others, but you could look up some of these terms in a thesaurus to see whether I've missed any common ones.

I hope this might have helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

you could technically call a man hag a scum, a blighter, or a curmudgeon. However, my personal favorite way to refer to a man hag is this: "A beastly confounded disgruntled old hoot of a man." You could also call him a scummy old hermit.

Comment: Thank you for answer, and you make a good point about the possible applicability of those terms to men as well, but opinion-based answers tend not to be very favourably looked upon here; we like research and the fleshing-out of topics.

Comment: Perhaps you meant: **old coot**.

Answer (score 1):

A casual word in everyday speech would be "git".  Although it might be more regional.